# python numpy.irr() will not work with more than 35 values

Tags: python, windows, numpy

when using the `np.irr()` function, 35 values seems to work

```
np.irr([-100.0] + ([25]*35))
```

but 35 vaues shuts down python.

```
np.irr([-100.0] + ([25]*36))
```

shuts down python

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0W73.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce on my mac, so I added a `windows` tag. What version of numpy/python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.9 :: Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested on windows here with 1.10.4/Python 2.7.3 32-bit, and cannot replicate the crash even with much larger lists (3000 items!), however I do notice with Process Explorer that Python's RAM usage is skyrocketing.

This makes sense as the [25]*36 is allocating a list of that length, then passing it to the fn, calculating, then returning.  It appears that .irr does not support generators as input, which is a bit annoying if you were to attempt this type of function on very large iterables. Numpy does not appear to be releasing all memory used here after the fn has finished, which could be causing an issue as well.

On Anaconda, can you specify whether Numpy is built with Intel Math Kernel Library (MKL)? This was an option building it locally and I did choose this.  My understanding is MKL is used to optimize over multi-core.  An error in a compiled dependency (like a DLL) could manifest in a full crash of the process similar to what you are seeing.

Sorry that this is posted as an answer (should be a comment but I can't comment yet due to < 50 reputation).